# No dash lights or exterior lights, no crank, and no power

Tags: electrical, ford, starting, mustang

05 V6 Mustang ... I drove the car for about 10 mins at 55mph. After switching off, I came back and go to start my car. No dash lights appear, starter doesn’t click, and no exterior lights work. Checked all my fuses and relays none were blown. Put the battery on a charger and sat for several hours. Still does not start. I need help considering this is my daily driver, I can’t think of anything significant other than it being the battery, the fuse box, or a ground. Wondering if this has happened to anyone else or if anyone knows what it could be?

Answer (score 3):

I'd be looking at 2 things: has the ignition switch failed/ main feed wire come off? Are the battery connections both at the terminals and the ground strap, good clean and tight?

Total power loss, including lights that normally work with the key off, points to a battery disconnection.

If you have a test light or some other way to check the battery is actually charged, just see if there's 12-13V at the terminals. If there is, check if there is 12V between the + terminal and any convenient spot on the chassis (a bolt or some other nearby metal surface).

If the battery has 12V, and there's voltage to ground, then look at the ignition switch and associated wiring for loose/broken wires etc.